# how to search the database through a specific parameter in a child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how json Firebase realtime looks like:

```
[ {
  "author" : "Абуабдулло Рудаки",
  "id" : 1,
  "text" : "Все зубы выпали мои, и понял я впервые,\n..."
}, {
  "author" : "Абуабдулло Рудаки",
  "id" : 2,
  "text" : "В благоухании, в цветах пришла желанная весна\n...",
  "title" : "В благоухании, в цветах пришла"
},
```

[image]

I have no name for the object of the verse. I need to get those verses whose title is equal to a variable without knowing the name of the parent object

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("poems").orderByChild("id").equalTo("10").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                search_output value = snapshot.getValue(search_output.class);
                states.add(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                throw error.toException();
            }
        });
```

Waring

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.easypoem, PID: 20870
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(AndroidPlatform.java:96)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7565)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 154796040 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 46MB until OOM, target footprint 245303656, growth limit 268435456
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3257)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:137)
        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.util.StringListReader.toString(StringListReader.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:254)
        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:300)
        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:34)
        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:86)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Updated: Changed function and got an error

Comment: That code looks fine to me at first glance, as long as a poem with title `example` exists. What isn't working about it?

Comment: listener does not work, function is not executed

Comment: Did you implement `onCancelled`? At its minimum, that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.